# Solve the equation $\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}-\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}=|5-x|$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Solve the equation $$\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}-\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}=|5-x|$$

> $x=5$ is the only real solution

We can note that $x^2-9x+24>0$ and $6x^2-59x+149>0$ for all $x$. The first thing I decided to try: as $$|5-x|=\begin{cases}5-x,x\le5\\x-5,x>5\end{cases},$$ we can look at two different cases based on the sign of $5-x$: let's $x>5$. Then the equation becomes $$\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}-\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}=x-5\\\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}=x-5+\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}\\x^2-9x+24=(x-5)^2+6x^2-59x+149+2(x-5)\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}\\30x-3x^2-7=(x-5)\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}$$ We have to raise both sides to the power of 2 again, so I decided to stop here.

Something else we can try is to raise both sides of the initial equation to the power of 2, as $|5-x|^2=(5-x)^2,$ so we have $$7x^2-68x+173-2\sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)}=x^2-10x+25\\3x^2-29x+72=\sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)}$$ I think it's obvious I am missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since, $|5-x|\geqslant 0$, then you have:

$$\begin{align}&\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}-\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}\geqslant 0\\
\iff &x^2-9x+24\geqslant 6x^2-59x+149\geqslant 0\\
\iff &-5(x-5)^2\geqslant 0\\
\iff &x=5. \end{align}$$

This implies that, if there's a solution, then it is $5$. Indeed, $x=5$ is a solution.

---

Remember that, sometimes it is easier to find the domain of the equation than to solve the equation itself.  That's exactly what we're doing in this equation.

Comment: That's really clever, thank you! May I ask you do we need to previously clarify in the solution that $\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}$ and $\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}$ are defined for all real $x$?

Comment: I might be wrong but doesn't this show you that $x =5$ *could* be a solution and that $x=5$ is the only possible solution, but it *doesn't* show us that $x=5$ actually *is* a solution.  It's always possible there is not solution.

Comment: @fleablood You are right . Your comment seems equivalent to saying why we should use the "If...,then..." statement here. This is noted in my answer.

Comment: @KaloyanK.  Note that, $$A≥B≥0\iff A≥B\wedge B≥0. $$ Therefore, we need only checking $\Delta_x<0$ for $6x^2-59x+149$. Our attempts, also use this fact.

Comment: @lonestudent Yes,  on reading you did state that.  But perhaps subtly.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
x^2-9x+24&=(x-5)^2+(x-5)+4\\
6x^2-59x+149&=6(x-5)^2+(x-5)+4
\end{align*}
Say $(x-5)^2+(x-5)+4=\alpha$ (note $\alpha \geq 0$), then we have
$$\sqrt{\alpha}-\sqrt{5(x-5)^2+\alpha}=|5-x|$$
The expression on the left is $\leq 0$ and that on the right is $\geq 0$. For the equality to hold, both have to be $0$.

Thus $x=5$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well we must have the following conditions.

$x^2 -9x +24 \ge 0$ (other wise the square root doesn't exist)

$6x^2 - 59x + 149 \ge 0$.  (ditto)

$\sqrt{x^2 - 9x + 24} \ge \sqrt{6x^2 - 59x + 149}$ (because their difference is $|5-x|$ which is $\ge 0$)

$x^2 - 9x + 24 \ge 6x^2 - 59x + 149$ (because $0 \le a \le b \implies a^2 \le b^2$)

So $5x^2 - 50x + 125 \le 0$.  We can factor to get

$5(x-5)^2 \le 0$. and we'll.. that actually throws me throw a loop... I was only trying to find a valid range that $x$ can be in but this is ... big.

$(x-5)^2$ is a perfect square and so $(x-5)^2 \ge 0$ so the only way we can have $5(x-5)^2 \le 0$ is if $(x-5)^2 = 0$ and $x = 5$.

So *if* there is any answer the only possible answer is $x=5$.

But that doesn't mean that there *is* any answer.  After all anyone can write down anything.  That doesn't mean it has an answer.

So we have to check that if $x=5$ the equation holds.

If $x =5$ then $x^2 -9x + 24 = 25-45 + 24 = 4$ and $\sqrt{x^2 -9x+24} = 2$.

And $6x^2 - 59x + 149= 150 -295 + 149= 4$ and $\sqrt{6x^2 - 59x + 149} = 2$.

And $|5-x| = |5-5|=0$ and $\sqrt{x^2 -9x+24} - \sqrt{6x^2 - 59x + 149}=2-2=0=|5-x|$ and thus $x = 5$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track (except for a slight arithmetic error) by squaring both sides.  This gives you:

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2-9x+24}-\sqrt{6x^2-59x+149}\right)^2=(5-x)^2$$
$$(x^2-9x+24) - 2\sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)} + (6x^2-59x+149)=25-10x+x^2$$
$$7x^2 - 68x + 173 - 2\sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)}=x^2-10x+25$$
$$6x^2 - 58x + 148 = 2\sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)}$$
$$3x^2 - 29x + 74 = \sqrt{(x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)}$$

But once you reach this point, you can square both sides *again* to get a quartic polynomial equation.

$$(3x^2 - 29x + 74)^2 = (x^2-9x+24)(6x^2-59x+149)$$
$$9x^4 - 87x^3 + 222x^2 - 87x^3 + 841x^2 - 2146x + 222x^2 - 2146x + 5476 = 6x^4 - 59x^3 + 149x^2 - 54x^3 + 531x^2 - 1341x + 144x^2 - 1416x + 3576$$
$$9x^4 - 174x^3 + 1285x^2 - 4292x + 5476 = 6x^4 - 113x^3 + 824x^2 - 2757x + 3576$$
$$3x^4 - 61x^3 + 461x^2 - 1535x + 1900 = 0$$

You can use the Rational Root Theorem to find the roots $x \in \{4, 5, \frac{19}{3}\}$.  Then factor out $(x-4)(x-5)(3x-19)$ to get $x-5$.  So $5$ is actually a *double* root, and $4$ and $\frac{19}{3}$ are single roots, giving us the 4 roots guaranteed by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

But we're not done yet: We have to make sure that the roots satisfy the *original* equation.

$$x = 4 \implies 2-3=1 \implies -1=1$$
$$x = 5 \implies 2-2=0 \implies 0=0$$
$$x = \frac{19}{3} \implies \frac{8}{3}-4=\frac{4}{3} = \implies -\frac{4}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$$

So, $x = 4$ and $x = \frac{19}{3}$ are extraneous solutions introduced by the squaring, but $x=5$ checks out.